# Android Google Map API - программно указать ключ

Tags: android, google-maps-api, key

Как инициализировать карты google в Android, указав ключ программно?

К примеру, я хочу, чтобы ключ получался с сервера или хранился в переменной.

Comment: что мешает зашить ключ в самой программе?

Comment: Ничего не мешает. Но нам этого не надо.

Comment: может [поможет](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386770/generating-google-map-release-api-key).

Comment: Я думаю ,что его нельзя указать программно потому, чтобы нельзя было при помощи нескольких разных ключей превышать лимит запросов к `Google Maps API` для одного приложения. Если бы можно было программно указать ключ, то вы бы имели бесплатный безлимитный доступ к `Google Maps API`. Вы наверно для этого и хотите его указать программно?